# What parts of a Compaq Presario v6000 laptop are reusable?

Tags: laptop, recycling

I have a Compaq Presario v6000 that fails to work anymore, the casing and hard drive are shot.  I want to know if any parts from it are "standard" enough to work in a budget system.

Also, I realize I can find this out by opening it up... ~_~

Answer (score 2):

If I get a non working laptop, I typically (but not limited to) do the following -

Take out, Hard drive, memory, cpu and the screen.

If the hard drive is bad, it is good to keep as spares as you may one day need to use the board on a different hard drive (if you have no plans on ever doing this, don't bother).

Screen - if in good condition / able to clean, then I sell them as second hand on repairs (can easily get £50 each), and if in bad condition, I take out the CCFL tube.

CPU - Well, usually eBay is the best bet if I can't re use

Memory - For the stash! - and again, offer cheaper for second hand upgrades.

---

#### Extras (but not always recommended)

Keyboards - Take a look, People actually sell individual keys on eBay!

Anything else - eBay again! take a look, people sell anything that can be unscrewed and removed, from chassis to other parts.

I used to also unsolder the DC jack and a few other components that can get burnt easily, but it is more trouble than it's worth and I would rather send off to a third party so I get a warranty and don't have to worry about warranty on returns.

The same place, I give the used chassis to and they give me a discount when I need other repairs done - if there is any place local to you, you may want to try and get a similar deal.

Comment: Well, thank you for this response.  Most of the laptop is still usable.  It can still boot, but the hard drive is unresponsive, the chassis is damaged, so you have to prop it up in place, and the cooling system is damaged, so I can't leave it on for too long.

Comment: Try unscrewing the fan / repairing it or just ordering a replacement - I think you can get straight from HP for around £30, you can also get new hard drives for not that much.... But do you just mean it locks up after a few minutes?

Comment: No, I can usually get about an hour out of it.  It seems that some parts of the cooling system still function.

Comment: Well, obviously without saying, get your important data off QUICK! thermal problems are usually identified by shutdowns, not lock ups... replacing memory or hard drive could give you a few more years out of your machine.

Comment: @Wil.  I already got all my data off it.  Now I have the laptop and it's not being used for anything.  I was wondering if I could use the good parts for something else.